# Using jQuery dropdown box event to change a JS element

Tags: jquery, sparql

I am trying to use a jQuery dropdown box event to replace a piece of SPARQL that has been assigned to an element.

The code I use does not seem to be working:

```
var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body')
$(sel).change(function (){
    if() {
        $(sparqlquery).replaceWith("UPDATED SPARQL");
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery is not an acronym.

Comment: Your `if` construct misses a condition

Comment: sorry, didnt mean to include the incorrect if, not supposed to be there, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var sel = $('select').appendTo('body');
$(sel).change(function(){
    $(sparqlquery).replaceWith("UPDATED SPARQL");               
});
```

This at least fixes the code you just pasted, but I have no idea if this actually fixes your problem. For that I would need to see the HTML and get more context.